# Enter password: mysqldump: Got error: 1045: Access denied for user 'XXX'@'localhost' (using password: NO) when trying to connect

Tags: php, sql, cpanel

I'm trying to write a PHP code that will backup my SQL database daily. However, running it using a Cron Job spits out the above error in the title. My server is hosted on hostgator and its a shared server.

The dbuser has all privileges granted.

Here's my code:

```
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'XXXX';
$dbpass = 'XXXX';

$backupFile = $dbname . date("Y-m-d-H-i-s") . '.gz';
$command = "mysqldump --opt -h $dbhost -u $dbuser -p $dbpass $dbname | gzip > $backupFile";
system($command);
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

your problem is the space between "-p" and $dbpass. The command mysqldump hopes "-ppassword" together (the response is "using password: no" for this).

Try:

```
$command = "mysqldump --opt -h $dbhost -u $dbuser -p$dbpass $dbname | gzip > $backupFile";
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code worked for me:

```
$DBUSER="XXX";
$DBPASSWD="XXXX";
$DATABASE="XXXXX";
$filename = "backup-" . date("d-m-Y") . ".sql.gz";
$cmd = "mysqldump -u $DBUSER --password=$DBPASSWD $DATABASE | gzip --best > $filename";
passthru( $cmd );

exit(0);
```